# How to use SharePoint REST API to get newest list item?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, ajax, orderby

I am trying to get the newest item added to a list.

Get item by ID works for single item:

```
$.ajax({
url: xurl + "/_api/web/lists('" + xlist + "')/items/getById(123)", 
type: "GET", headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", },
  success: function (data) {
    var xid = data.d.ID;
    alert(xid);},
  error: function (error) { alert(JSON.stringify(error)); }
});
```

Get top item, doesn't work, it returns `undefined`:

```
$.ajax({
url: xurl + "/_api/web/lists('" + xlist + "')/items?$top=1&$orderby=ID desc", 
type: "GET", headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", },
  success: function (data) {
    var xid = data.d.ID;
    alert(xid);},
  error: function (error) { alert(JSON.stringify(error)); }
});
```

Suggestions?

Comment: In your first code, you can also use the url as items(123).

Comment: faced the same issue. did the above comment work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL and endpoint seems right.

But in success, you will get the return data in `data.d.results` array.

So you can extract the ID of item from  `data.d.results` array.

In this case, You will not get the ID of item directly using `data.d.ID`.

Try adding below code in success function:

```
if(data.d.results.length > 0) {
    var xid = data.d.results[0].ID;
    console.log(xid);
}
```

Comment: Are you able to get the item ID using this code?

Comment: per above, "/items" returns a collection of zero or more items.

Comment: nice! am learning, this site is the best resource ever!

Comment: Yes, /items returns the collection. But using $top=1 will always return just single item.